# How to structure Firebase data and rules for sharing data between users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Currently I have a simple todo app whereby users can create a list then tick off items as done. The data is structured as follows: '/acc_' + USER_ID +'/done' and '/acc_' + USER_ID +'/todo'. As items are "done" they are moved to the done list.

What I'd like is for a user to be able to share a list with another authenticated user.

The rules currently look like the following which seem to work.

```
{
  "rules": {
        "$userPath": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null",
            ".validate": "$userPath === 'acc_' + auth.id"
        }
    }
}
```

What I think I need to do is have each user having an array of approved email addresses have somehow hook that into the security rules.

Alternatively I could make a list in the root and have only the creator and shared users access it.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 1):

Since the user decides who'd they like to share the list with, I'd store that information in the user data itself. For example:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "$userPath": {
      ".write": "$userPath == 'acc_' + auth.id",
      ".read": "$userPath == 'acc_' + auth.id || root.child($userPath).child('shared').hasChild(auth.id)"
    }
  }
}
```

And then store the list of users the data is shared with in `acc_userid/shared/`

Comment: I didn't have much luck with the above rules. This following appeared to work though with 'acc_' + auth.id '/shared' being an array where the first entry being the one I want to have access. Although, in hindsight, this doesn't seem like a great solution. I think my problems with architecture of the app are deep.
{
  "rules": {
    "$userPath": {
      ".write": "$userPath == 'acc_' + auth.id || root.child($userPath).child('shared').child('0').val() == auth.email",
      ".read": "$userPath == 'acc_' + auth.id || root.child($userPath).child('shared').child('0').val() == auth.email"
    }
  }
}