# How to store data per user and prevent others to see them

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I wonder if it's possible to have the following things with Firebase:

- handle several users in a Firebase application
- a user can signup using OAuth2 and external providers like Google
- each user has its own set of data
- other users can't see the data of a specific user

Firebase would be used from a frontend Web application without server-side application.

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that all of your requirements are met.

See the docs: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html

[image]

With a slight modification your security rules can be as follow:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you think that it's possible to implement a "share data" feature basing on similar configuration?

Comment: "share data" feature - what that would be? An user sharing data with another one? First thoughts - denomarlizing data but not sure how to keep it in sync and not duplicating too much... Related: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html

Comment: The ability for a user to see protected data of another user if the latter allows it. Thanks very much for the link :-)

Comment: I think to something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306489/how-to-share-data-between-users-in-firebase...

Comment: Clever: ```".write" : "root.child('users').child($user_id).child('friends').hasChild(auth.uid)"``` (thanks for sharing)